# Why does water flow up the sides?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

Ive noticed this on my faucet and wonder why water flows up the sides?  Is it dark magic?

[image]

Comment: well I think it is kind of black magic because your water not only goes up but weirdly goes to the right also. I think it is dark water - named after dark matter. Jokes aside. I think you need to decalcify your tab. The exit is narrowed and the water comes out chaotically.

Comment: So much water wasted :-) Jokes apart, what is the geometry of the outlet orifice? Does this climbing up happen at high flow rates too?

Comment: @Deep i dunno... i will have to check it out